# Cannot Write File in Electron App After Build

Tags: node.js, electron, fs, electron-builder

I know this is a repetitious question but i can't find any answer

I want to store my electron app data in a local json file

This works very good but after packaging and building it doesn't work

I tried to run app in administrator but that doesn't work again!

i don't know how to solve this problem

There is a way to store data in electron app **No Matter How**

thanks

Comment: Since electron is a packaged/bundled app and directories are different than running a normal node.js app, perhaps you don't have an appropriate path to write to.  You're more likely to find someone who can help if you show the relevant code.

Comment: i use relative path, i think this is not the case, is it 
 incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you saving this file? Unless you have admin access, you can't save to certain directories because that would expose a lot of potential security holes of written apps.

There was a [package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store#electron-store-) written that allows you to save data in a file for your app, making use of the path of [`app.getPath("userData")`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname). This is the magic path you need to be using, `app.getPath("userData")`. If you aren't saving your data to this path, you will require admin access.

That package although makes use of outdated security practices, so if you want to still save your electron data to a file with better practices (ie. using IPC instead of the [remote](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/remote) module), I'd recommend this [template](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template) that I am an author of.